Can i spray base coat over sanded base coat
I'm not too sure? I used a 2k primer on my Corvette which made the base orange peel so I decided that I will sand down the base till smooth. Most of the base coat is off down to the primer. It is now smooth, but not all of it. If I respray the base it may have highs and lows. Should I reprime again? It was my mom's Vette. I want it to come out nice.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is the Vette and does it have original paint?

1980 yes it's original paint

I wet sanded it down with 320

When you say a "base coat", that seems like you're saying you are going to put it down then spray clear over the top of it. I'm pretty sure most OEM paints are single stage paint, meaning the base coat doubles as the top coat. You can spray your base coat on top of sanded base, but you'll probably want finer sandpaper. The scratches from 320 will show. You do need some texture, though, as otherwise you won't get mechanical adhesion and the paint will peel. I'm leaving this as a comment, because really I don't know much "for sure" about paint and body work.

Thank you yes you spray primer then base coat then clear waiting 15 to 30 minutes each coat my problem was 2k primer.i sprayed the base coat on that primer and it orange peeled.with my experience in painting I decided to wet sand the base coat smooth with 320 since it's fiberglass you cat DA it.All sanding has to be hand sanded.My question is since most of the base coat is off do I prime or reapply the base coat.

Personally I'd think you could go either way, but might do you well to go primer, base, clear in your original order ... the primer will stick, then everything else will stick as you build up. At least that's my thinking.

That's what I think just wanted someone to double Check me thanks
